# PHP form with function argument

Tags: php, forms, function, return

I have this php code:

```
<?php
        echo '<form action="index.php" method="post">
                <h3>ggjnjskrngjekrng</h3>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="nbmatchs" />
                    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
                </p>
                </form>';
        echo getLastMatchs($nbmatchs);
        ?>
```

My function:

```
function getLastMatchs(int $nb) {
    $i=0;
    while ($nb < $i )
    {
    return 'hello';
    $i++;
    }
}
```

And i want return for exemple if nbmatchs is 5, return 5x "Hello".
How can i do ?

I have this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: nbmatchs in C:\...

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to getLastMatchs() must be an instance of int, null given, called in C:\.. and defined in C:\...
```

Comment: From php.net: Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string. Resources and Traits are not allowed either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems kind of pointless, but:

```
echo getLastMatchs($_POST['nbmatchs']);

function getLastMatchs($nb) {
    return str_repeat('hello', (int)$nb);
}
```

Comment: There really is a native function for (almost) everything :D

Comment: Thanks, work, but i i want sql result, i just need ad sql line or change somthing other ?

Comment: @flavien317:  I have no idea what you want.  There is nothing to do with SQL in your question.  Start another question and explain the SQL question.